The data is not updated when useState uses setState
I have a very simple useState use code as follows:
const [roomNumber, setRoomNumber] = React.useState([]);
 setRoomNumber((prev) => {
      const next = prev;
      next.push('');
      return next;
    });

In my understanding, setState was used to update the data and the data should be updated normally after return was used. Why did it not update when I used this method? I also used useEffect to print without any effect
However, if I go back to vscode to save the code, these push contents will all be displayed at once. I have tried this for many times. I want to know whether the way I used setState is wrong or there is a problem with the scaffolding of vite?
I am wondering if the new version has changed the content of useState or is there something that I have no idea about at the moment
This is my page.json file:
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^5.3.7",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1",
    "antd": "^5.18.3",
    "less": "^4.2.0",
    "less-loader": "^12.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.21.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^5.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "electron": "^29.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.1.0"
  }


next = prev is not a copy.

you are passing reference of the array on next = prev

you are updating the variable using push method in your example, as a result you return the same reference as before so it doesn't detect any change.
You just need to return a new reference like this :
setRoomNumber((prev) => [...prev, '']);


According to what you said, is it correct that I can understand that my operation is to assign the address of the reference data type to next and then push the operation on next, which is equivalent to pushing the original roomNumber directly, causing it to not detect the change of data, so it will not change and use it [...prev, ""] is equal to copy and generate a new array, so that he can know that the data has changed and re-render the view (sorry, it may be a bit of a problem to express it, I don't know English well)
